# Exponent out of range: convert positive decimal number into floating point 3 bits exponent 5 bits mantissa format

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, ieee-754

I have to convert decimal `21` into floating point 3 bits exponent 5 bits mantissa format, but exponent must by in Two's complement code.

I did it according to the algorithm presented here: http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/dtof.html

I normalize the value:
`21 decimal = 10101 x 2^0 = 1.0101 x 2^4` so the 5 bits mantissa is: `01010`

According to point E. in given article the bias for 3 bits exponent field is `2^(3-1)-1 = 3` I add the bias to the exponent `4 + 3 = 7` which is `0111` in Two's complement code on 4 bits but my exponent have 3 bits.

I have been told that exponent field for this example should be `001` but I don't know why.

Question: Why exponent field should be `001`?

Comment: The biased exponent is an unsigned number, here `4d+3d=111b`. The answer `001b` is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're totally right. I've just spotted that person who told that `001` is exponent made foundation that exponent must be in Two's complement code.

Comment: `4d` cannot be written in 3 bits using the two's complement representation (the representable range is `-4d` to `3d`). That person probably used `4d-3d=001b`, which is the wrong way to apply bias.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok, I'll check it and report after I find out.

Comment: @Yoda 1. the mantisa is `10101b` not `01010` (probably typo) or am i missing something? 2. if the exponent is in two's complement what is the meaning of bias? It makes no sense ... you have either bias and standard `uint` binary or **2's** complement and **no bias**.